# on changing orientation of screen, i want to stretch image first before rotation

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am working on an application where we can see images in landscape as well as portrait view. now i want that when orientation of screen changed to landscape mode, the size of image stretched to full size and then rotate. how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the stretching in the following method...

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
     // Stretch Here
}
```

Comment: when i am changing the orientation of screen, the image will pop out from corner. i want it to pop out from center.